# FSL- Bulk Work Order Creation Fail

Tags: fsl

We are trying to perform bulk work order creation from a contract through a lightning component. For this, we are using an Apex class. However, during bulk testing, we encountered multiple flow errors. To address this issue, we created a batch class to handle CPU limits, but we still encountered the same error. After creating a future callout, we are still facing the same error.

-USER_DEBUG caused by: FSL.Exceptions.GeneralException: Callout from triggers are currently not supported.

-This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: FSL.TR021_AssignedResource_AfterInsert: execution of AfterInsert caused by: FSL.Exceptions.GeneralException: Callout from triggers are currently not supported. (System Code). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: FSL.TR021_AssignedResource_AfterInsert: execution of AfterInsert caused by: FSL.Exceptions.GeneralException: Callout from triggers are currently not supported. (System Code). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Could you please investigate this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems clear that your apex is trying to perform a callout (directly or via some FSL API) from a record triggered flow or apex trigger. Take a look at [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) and [this github example](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) around how you can have callouts (indirectly) through triggers.